# Scipy Lognorm.rvs variance not matching what's expected

Tags: scipy

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import lognorm

loc = 0
s = 2.4 #I believe this is sigma
scale = np.exp(7.6) #I believe this is mu

samples_lognorm = lognorm.rvs(loc=loc, s=s, scale=scale, size=1000000)

samples.lognorm.var()
```

The variance equals about 206,844,501,130

$Var=[exp(\sigma^2)-1] * exp(2\mu+\sigma^2)=[exp(2.4^2-1)]* exp(2*7.6+2.4^2)\approx 400,846,305,687$

```
mean, var, skew, kurt = lognorm.stats(s=2.4, loc=0, scale=np.exp(7.6), moments='mvsk')
print(f'{mean}, {var}, {skew}, {kurt}')
```

This gives the correct variance, 400,846,305,687

I've tried increasing the number of samples all the way up to one billion, but that hasn't helped. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Given the *extraordinary* skewness of your chosen distribution, it's remarkable that the sample variance is even the right order of magnitude!  A far better test will use much smaller values of $\sigma$ -- start with values between $0$ and $1.$

Comment: @whuber Thanks for pointing that out. The $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are from an actuarial science paper on increased limit factors. Maybe the author gave the wrong value for $\sigma$.

Comment: Or possibly the logarithm of $2.4,$ equal to $0.9$ or so, is $\sigma.$  Realistic values of $\sigma$ (the geometric SD) for Lognormal distributions are usually less than $0.6$ and almost always less than $1.5$ in my experience.